# threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I am trying to re-create the MifareClassicTool (see https://github.com/ikarus23/MifareClassicTool). Highly appreciate if someone could help me out.  I get an error message in the LogCat and it reads:

```
07-28 18:23:02.489: D/AndroidRuntime(338): Shutting down VM
07-28 18:23:02.489: W/dalvikvm(338): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.syss.MifareClassicTool/de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/de.syss.MifareClassicTool-1.apk]
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/de.syss.MifareClassicTool-1.apk]
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
07-28 18:23:02.639: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  ... 11 more
07-28 18:28:02.672: I/Process(338): Sending signal. PID: 338 SIG: 9
```

My code in MainActivity file is:

```
    package com.example.mifareclassictool_3;

    import java.io.File;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
    import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
    import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.ContextMenu;
    import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import de.syss.MifareClassicTool.R;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       private static final String LOG_TAG =
           MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

       private final static int FILE_CHOOSER_DUMP_FILE = 1;
       private final static int FILE_CHOOSER_KEY_FILE = 2;
       private AlertDialog mEnableNfc;
       private Button mReadTag;
       private Button mWriteTag;
       private boolean mResume = true;
       private Intent mOldIntent = null;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMainFooter);
       tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
       try {
          String appVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        tv.setText(TextUtils.concat(getString(R.string.app_version), ": ",
                appVersion, " - ", getText(R.string.text_footer)));
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
           Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Version not found.");
       }

        Button tools = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainTools);
        registerForContextMenu(tools);

       Common.setNfcAdapter(NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this));
       if (Common.getNfcAdapter() == null) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_no_nfc_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_no_nfc)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_exit_app,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
             })
             .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    finish();
                }
             })
             .show();
        mResume = false;
        return;
         }

        if (Common.isExternalStorageWritableErrorToast(this)) {
        // Create keys directory.
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Common.HOME_DIR) + Common.KEYS_DIR);
        if (path.exists() == false && !path.mkdirs()) {
            // Could not create directory.
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while crating '" + Common.HOME_DIR
                    + Common.KEYS_DIR + "' directory.");
            return;
        }

        path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Common.HOME_DIR) + Common.DUMPS_DIR);
        if (path.exists() == false && !path.mkdirs()) {
            // Could not create directory.
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while crating '" + Common.HOME_DIR
                    + Common.DUMPS_DIR + "' directory.");
            return;
        }

        path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Common.HOME_DIR) + Common.TMP_DIR);
        if (path.exists() == false && !path.mkdirs()) {
            // Could not create directory.
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while crating '" + Common.HOME_DIR
                    + Common.TMP_DIR + "' directory.");
            return;
        }
        for (File file : path.listFiles()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        if (!hasStdKeysFile()) {
            createStdKeysFile();
        }
        }

        mReadTag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainReadTag);
        mWriteTag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainWriteTag);

        mEnableNfc = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_nfc_not_enabled_title)
        .setMessage(R.string.dialog_nfc_not_enabled)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_nfc,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Goto NFC Settings.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                }
            }
         })
         .setNeutralButton(R.string.action_editor_only,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Only use Editor. Do nothing.
            }
         })
         .setNegativeButton(R.string.action_exit_app,
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Exit the App.
                finish();
            }
         }).create();

         // Show first usage notice.
          SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         boolean isFirstRun = sharedPref.getBoolean("is_first_run", true);
         if (isFirstRun) {
         Editor e = sharedPref.edit();
         e.putBoolean("is_first_run", false);
         e.commit();
         new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_first_run_title)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_first_run)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    mResume = true;
                    checkNfc();
                }
             })
            .show();
          mResume = false;
        }
        }


       @Override
       public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.dialog_tools_menu_title);
       menu.setHeaderIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences);
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.tools, menu);
       // Enable/Disable tag info tool depending on NFC availability.
       menu.findItem(R.id.menuMainTagInfo).setEnabled(
            Common.getNfcAdapter() != null
            && Common.getNfcAdapter().isEnabled());
       }

       * If resuming is allowed because all dependencies from
       * {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} are satisfied, call
       * {@link #checkNfc()}
       * @see #onCreate(Bundle)
       * @see #checkNfc()
       */
       @Override
       public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();

        if (mResume) {
        checkNfc();
        }
       }

       /**
       * Check if NFC adapter is enabled. If not, show the user a dialog and let
       * him choose between "Goto NFC Setting", "Use Editor Only" and "Exit App".
       * Also enable NFC foreground dispatch system.
       * @see Common#enableNfcForegroundDispatch(Activity)
       */
       private void checkNfc() {
       // Check if the NFC hardware is enabled.
       if (Common.getNfcAdapter() != null
            && !Common.getNfcAdapter().isEnabled()) {
        // NFC is disabled. Show dialog.
        mEnableNfc.show();
        // Disable read/write tag options.
        mReadTag.setEnabled(false);
        mWriteTag.setEnabled(false);
        return;
        } else {
        // NFC is enabled. Hide dialog and enable NFC
        // foreground dispatch.
        if (mOldIntent != getIntent()) {
            if (Common.treatAsNewTag(getIntent(), this) == 0) {
                // Device or tag does not support Mifare Classic.
                // Run the only thing that is possible: The tag info tool.
                Intent i = new Intent(this, TagInfoToolActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            mOldIntent = getIntent();
        }
        Common.enableNfcForegroundDispatch(this);
        mEnableNfc.hide();
        mReadTag.setEnabled(true);
        mWriteTag.setEnabled(true);
        }
       }

       * Disable NFC foreground dispatch system.
       * @see Common#disableNfcForegroundDispatch(Activity)
       */
       @Override
       public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       Common.disableNfcForegroundDispatch(this);
       }

       /**
       * Handle new Intent as a new tag Intent and if the tag/device does not
       * support Mifare Classic, then run {@link TagInfoToolActivity}.
       * @see Common#treatAsNewTag(Intent, android.content.Context)
       * @see TagInfoToolActivity
       */
       @Override
       public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       if (Common.treatAsNewTag(intent, this) == 0) {
         // Device or tag does not support Mifare Classic.
        // Run the only thing that is possible: The tag info tool.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TagInfoToolActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
       }
       }

       /**
       * Show the {@link ReadTagActivity}.
       * @param view The View object that triggered the method
       * (in this case the read tag button).
       * @see ReadTagActivity
       */
       public void onShowReadTag(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReadTagActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       }

       /**
       * Show the {@link WriteTagActivity}.
       * @param view The View object that triggered the method
       * (in this case the write tag button).
       * @see WriteTagActivity
       */
       public void onShowWriteTag(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, WriteTagActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       }

       /**
       * Show the help Activity.
       * @param view The View object that triggered the method
       * (in this case the help/info button).
       */
       public void onShowHelp(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       }

       /**
       * Show the tools menu (as context menu).
       * @param view The View object that triggered the method
       * (in this case the tools button).
       */
       public void onShowTools(View view) {
       openContextMenu(view);
       }

       /**
       * Open a file chooser ({@link FileChooserActivity}). The
       * Activity result will be processed in
       * {@link #onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)}.
       * If the dump files folder is empty display an additional error
       * message.
       * @param view The View object that triggered the method
       * (in this case the show/edit tag dump button).
       * @see FileChooserActivity
       * @see #onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)
       */
        public void onOpenTagDumpEditor(View view) {
        String dumpsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Common.HOME_DIR) + Common.DUMPS_DIR;
        if (Common.isExternalStorageWritableErrorToast(this)) {
        File file = new File(dumpsDir);
        if (file.isDirectory() && (file.listFiles() == null
                || file.listFiles().length == 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.info_no_dumps,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FileChooserActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_DIR, dumpsDir);
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_TITLE,
                getString(R.string.text_open_dump_title));
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_BUTTON_TEXT,
                getString(R.string.action_open_dump_file));
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_ENABLE_DELETE_FILE, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER_DUMP_FILE);
        }
        }

        /**
        * Open a file chooser ({@link FileChooserActivity}). The
        * Activity result will be processed in
        * {@link #onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)}.
        * @param view The View object that triggered the method
        * (in this case the show/edit key button).
        * @see FileChooserActivity
        * @see #onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)
        */
        public void onOpenKeyEditor(View view) {
        if (Common.isExternalStorageWritableErrorToast(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FileChooserActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_DIR,
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Common.HOME_DIR) + Common.KEYS_DIR);
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_TITLE,
                getString(R.string.text_open_key_file_title));
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_BUTTON_TEXT,
                getString(R.string.action_open_key_file));
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_ENABLE_NEW_FILE, true);
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_ENABLE_DELETE_FILE, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER_KEY_FILE);
        }
        }

        /**
        * Handle (start) the selected tool from the tools menu.
        */
        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuMainTagInfo:
        intent = new Intent(this, TagInfoToolActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
        case R.id.menuMainValueBlockCoder:
        intent = new Intent(this, ValueBlockToolActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
        default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
        }

        /**
        * Run the {@link DumpEditorActivity} or the {@link KeyEditorActivity}
        * if file chooser result is O.K.
        * @see DumpEditorActivity
        * @see KeyEditorActivity
        * @see #onOpenTagDumpEditor(View)
        * @see #onOpenKeyEditor(View)
        */
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {
        case FILE_CHOOSER_DUMP_FILE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DumpEditorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_CHOSEN_FILE,
                    data.getStringExtra(
                            FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_CHOSEN_FILE));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        break;
        case FILE_CHOOSER_KEY_FILE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, KeyEditorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_CHOSEN_FILE,
                    data.getStringExtra(
                            FileChooserActivity.EXTRA_CHOSEN_FILE));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        break;
        }
        }

        /**
        * Create a standard key file ({@link Common#STD_KEYS}) in
        * {@link Common#KEYS_DIR}. This file contains some std. Mifare keys:
        * <ul>
        * <li>0xFFFFFFFFFFFF - Unformatted, factory fresh tags.</li>
        * <li>0xA0A1A2A3A4A5 - First sector of the tag (Mifare MAD).</li>
        * <li>0xD3F7D3F7D3F7 - All other sectors.</li>
        * <li>Others from {@link Common#SOME_CLASSICAL_KNOWN_KEYS}.</li>
        * </ul>
        * The file is a simple text file, any plain text editor will do the trick.
        * Data from this App are stored in
        * getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Common.HOME_DIR) to remain
        * there after App uninstallation.
        * @see Common#SOME_CLASSICAL_KNOWN_KEYS
        * @see Common#KEYS_DIR
        * @see Common#HOME_DIR
        */
        private void createStdKeysFile() {
        // Create std. keys file.
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Common.HOME_DIR) + Common.KEYS_DIR, Common.STD_KEYS);
        String[] lines = new String[Common.SOME_CLASSICAL_KNOWN_KEYS.length+4];
        lines[0] = "# " + getString(R.string.text_std_keys_comment);
        lines[1] = Common.byte2HexString(MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT);
        lines[2] = Common.byte2HexString(
            MifareClassic.KEY_MIFARE_APPLICATION_DIRECTORY);
        lines[3] = Common.byte2HexString(MifareClassic.KEY_NFC_FORUM);
        System.arraycopy(Common.SOME_CLASSICAL_KNOWN_KEYS, 0,
            lines, 4, Common.SOME_CLASSICAL_KNOWN_KEYS.length);
        Common.saveFile(file, lines);
        }

        /**
        * Check if there is a {@link Common#STD_KEYS} file
        * in {@link Common#HOME_DIR}/{@link Common#KEYS_DIR}.
        * @return True if there is such a file, False otherwise.
        */
        private boolean hasStdKeysFile() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Common.HOME_DIR) + Common.KEYS_DIR, Common.STD_KEYS);
        return file.exists();
        }

        }
```

---

And the Manifest file is:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <!--
      /*

      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="de.syss.MifareClassicTool"
      android:versionCode="13"
      android:versionName="1.4.2" >

      <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="10"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

      <uses-feature
      android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
      android:required="true" />

      <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- NFC Tech Filter -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.CreateKeyMapActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/map_keys_to_sector"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_key_map"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.DumpEditorActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit_dump"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dump_editor" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.FileChooserActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/open"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_file_chooser"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity

     android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.AccessConditionDecoderActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/access_conditions"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_access_conditions"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.ValueBlocksToIntActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/value_block_to_int"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_value_blocks"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.WriteTagActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/write_tag"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_write_tag"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.ReadTagActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/read_tag"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_read_tag"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.KeyEditorActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit_keys"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_key_editor"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.HelpActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/help_and_info"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.HexToAsciiActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/hex_to_ascii"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hex_to_ascii"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.TagInfoToolActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/tag_info"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tag_info"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.ValueBlockToolActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/value_block_tool"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_value_block_tool"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
        </application>

        </manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, that's an huge amount of code; far too much code. Can you reduce it to a minimal example that still demonstrates the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your Logcat, you can see the Exception was caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.syss.MifareClassicTool.Activities.MainActivity
```

So take a look at your MainActivity.java. You define it in a different package that the one you point out in the manifest. So your first line on the MainActivity should be:

```
package de.syss.MifareClassicTool;
```

Not:

```
package com.example.mifareclassictool_3;
```

You can do it the other way around too (change the manifest).